# Why is $\Delta H = Q_P$ more useful than $\Delta U = Q$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I saw in a Khan Academy video that at constant pressure, we can essentially treat heat as a state variable, in that $\Delta H = Q_P$ can be traversed in one direction on an isobar and back, and the total enthalpy would be $\Delta H_2 - \Delta H_1 = Q_{P_2} - Q_{P_1}= 0$

However, when $dP = 0$, equivalently, $\implies W = 0 \implies \Delta U = Q $ so what's the point of this? Sal Khan noted the utility of enthalpy in the way I described in the beginning, but it seems that internal energy can serve the same function.

Comment: Where are you getting that $dP = 0 \Rightarrow W=0$? For a reversible process $W = -PdV$, so it depends on the change in volume, but the total pressure.

Comment: Ah, that must be my mistake. So I can't say $dP = 0 \implies \Delta U = Q$ but I can say $dP = 0 \implies \Delta H = Q$.

Comment: Yes. That's right

Answer (score 1):

***However, when =0, equivalently, ⟹=0⟹Δ= so what's the point of this? Sal Khan noted the utility of enthalpy in the way I described in the beginning, but it seems that internal energy can serve the same function.***

You are correct. There is no utility in using enthalpy over internal energy in the case of a closed system (no mass transfer). Its utility is when $\Delta P$ is not zero. For a closed system,

$$\Delta U=Q-P\Delta V$$

Internal energy only depends heat transfer and boundary work (change in volume work). But

$$\Delta H= \Delta U + P\Delta V + V\Delta P$$

If $\Delta V=0$ then

$$\Delta H= \Delta U + V\Delta P$$

$V\Delta P$ is referred to as flow work, the work involved in moving mass into and out of an open system. So $\Delta H$ encompasses both the change in internal energy and flow work, the latter not being applicable to a closed system.

Figure 1 below shows a generic open system with the input and output energy terms. The utility of $H$ is that it encompasses both the change in internal energy and the flow work, into one thermodynamic property. The figure can be  simplified for a number of special  cases, such as turbines, condensers, expansion valves, etc., where enthalpy is the single property that encompasses internal energy and flow work.

Figures 2 and 3 show special cases. Note how the single property enthalpy is used.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## First Law

Start from the IUPAC form of the first law for a closed system as below.

$$ dU = \delta q + \delta w$$

In this, heat and work that "leave" a system are negative. The Clausius form is an engineering approach that says, when work leaves, we get it and it should therefore be positive.

In the first law, the ONLY state function is $dU$. We should not fudge and say "at such and such conditions, heat becomes a state function". That approach short circuits the critical reasoning that is needed to recognize why. It becomes a mantra that is memorized, the fundamental meaning gets lost, and things go wrong fast, as in "Oh, but I heard somewhere that heat is a state function too ..."

Work has three basic forms: system expansion/contraction (mechanical) work, shaft work, and other work. The first becomes $-p dV$ (or $pdV$ in the Clausius form), with the sign convention tied up in the distinction between the direction of the change in volume and the direction of the applied force (an undergraduate physics textbook often is the best place to find the nuances, and some undergraduate engineering thermo books just wing it and make the substitution directly without reference to vector conventions).

The second form of work (shaft work) appears extensively in systems that have ... rotating shafts. The third form (other work) is such factors as electricity or light moving in or out of the system.

Take a closed system with no shaft or other work. We obtain

$$ dU = \delta q - pdV$$

In this expression, $U$, $p$, and $V$ are state variables of the system.

## Enthalpy

Enthalpy is defined as $H \equiv U + pV$. In the statistical mechanics paradigm of thermodynamics, internal energy is the molecular motion and configurations inside the system. Enthalpy includes the capacity of the system to do expansion work. An example is that two containers of ideal gas at the same $T$ will have the same specific internal energy. When they are at different $p$ or $\bar{V}$ (molar volume), they will have different specific enthalpies.

Expand the definition of enthalpy to obtain

$$dH = dU + d(pV) = \delta q + V dp $$

In this expression, $H$, $p$, and $V$ are state variables.

## Heat

Stay with a system that has no shaft or other work. In a process that occurs at constant volume, we find that $\delta q_V = dU$ and $dH = \delta q_V + Vdp$. In a process that occurs at constant pressure, we find that $\delta q_p = dH$ and $dU = \delta q_p + pdV$. Shaft or other work can be considered appropriately in the expressions as needed.

## What is the use?

First, we should never accept the statement that "heat can (essentially) be treated as a state variable". Heat is **never** a state variable. This heavily burdened shortcut may be behind part of your confusion.

Secondly, internal energy and enthalpy define two distinctly different state properties of a system. In the paradigm of the laws, we conserve internal energy (not enthalpy), and we add the capacity to do work to obtain enthalpy. In the paradigm of statistical mechanics, we tally up the molecular energy modes and the configuration modes to obtain internal energy, and we add the constraints of pressure and confinement on the system to obtain its enthalpy.

Finally, for a closed system with no shaft or other work, heat flow indicates a change in internal energy has occurred only when the system does not expand or contract, while heat flow indicates a change in internal energy has occurred only when the system pressure does not change.